# Magento 1.9.2.4 - Error Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, magento1.9.2.4

guys,

I recently installed an extension to display the installment price.

However, the following error appears in the log:

Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in /app/code/community/Contardi/Installments/Helper/Data.php on line 87

The code in the Data.php file is as follows:

```
public function getDescontoPrimeiraParcela($valorParcela)
{
    $percentual = $this->descontoPrimeiraParcela;
    $desconto = (float)(str_ireplace(',', '.', $percentual) / 100); // line 87
    if ($desconto) $valorParcela -= ($valorParcela * $desconto);
    return $valorParcela;
}
```

Does anyone know what can it be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which value do you get back for `$percentual = $this->descontoPrimeiraParcela`? It seems like it's not returning a numeric value. Maybe there's a percent sign in it or something that cannot be casted to a proper float value.

In general you could disable PHP Warnings through editing the index.php, more information about it here: https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Friend, I discovered the problem: the field descontoPrimeiraParcela is blank in the settings. That's why it doesn't return any numeric value. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Great. You're welcome